# Cisco VPN Client on Windows 7 64-bit?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, cisco-vpn-client

I just ordered a new Lenovo laptop with Windows 7 64-bit, and I heard that it doesn't support Cisco's VPN client.  The main work around that I saw: use XP mode.

Has anyone done this?  Does it work, or should I just get the 32-bit OS instead?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Cisco has recently released client 5.0.7 BETA that has Windows 64-bit support.

If you have a Cisco CCO login, here's the link...
[Cisco 5.0.7BETA VPN Client](http://tools.cisco.com/support/downloads/go/ImageList.x?relVer=5.0.7+Beta&mdfid=281940730&sftType=VPN+Client+Software&optPlat=Windows&nodecount=6&edesignator=null&modelName=Cisco+VPN+Client+v5.x&treeMdfId=268438162&modifmdfid=&imname=&treeName=Security&hybrid=&imst=)

EDIT - The current version 5.0.07.0290, officially supports Windows XP, Vista and 7 in both x86 and x64 flavors.

Comment: @ge0ff73, can you edit your answer to include a link?

Comment: Fantastic.  Can't wait to try it.

Comment: There was also a version of 4 that works, I use it to connect my 64-bit Windows 7 machine to the work network.

Comment: You can download here without logging in through Cisco, the 64-bit version works on my Windows 7 64-bit, but the 32-bit version does not work. http://www.helpdesk.ugent.be/vpn/en/akkoord.php

Answer (score 15):

I used the cisco VPN for a while within XP mode until I found Shrewsoft's VPN.  Shrewsoft works fine with my work's VPN (it imports PCF files). The development builds (2.1+) listed on their site support Win7 x64.

http://www.shrew.net/download/vpn

The problem I had with the Cisco client is while it did work ok in XP mode, you couldn't just run it like a program from Windows 7 (like most other programs you install in XP mode) without setting up some serious routing.

Comment: Nice! I don't have a Cisco CCO login. This VPN client looks better than Cisco's anyway. Works in almost any OS (incl. Win 7 x64). Thanks!

Comment: I agree this is way better than the Cisco Client.

Answer (score 2):

1. Install Cisco DNEupdate.
2. Reboot
3. Take ownership and delete ndis.sys (in c:\windows\system32\drivers).
4. Take ownership and delete ndis.sys.mui (in c:\windows\system32\drivers\en-us).
5. Install Cisco VPN Client 5.0.04.0300.
6. Reboot
7. Windows 7 will repair itself (should take a few seconds) and automatically reboot.
8. Cisco VPN Client should work without any other tweaks.
   Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Right step for install Cisco VPN Client on Windows 7 64-bit

1. Install dneupdate64  (this is a version for 64bit)
2. Reboot
3. MUST login with ComputerName\Administrator
4. Install Cisco VPN Client 5.0.07.0290 (this is a version for 64bit)

Answer (score -1):

I use Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client on a Windows 7 64 Bit plattform.

With Version 3.08075 I had the problem that Cisco tried to update the alreay up to date version with exiting the programm on trying to update. 
I couldnt turn off so Autoupdate & Check on connection but i found a work arround for my problem. If you encounter a similar problem try this workarround.

Start your controle management for services ("Dienste" in German) and search for Cisco. When you try to connect cisco will try to update and exit the process. Refresh the cisco service in your manager until you see it isnt running anymore. During that time the update and connecting process is still running. Restart the cisco service before this process ends and you should be able to connect.

Comment: AnyConnect is another VPN Software ! Ramhound .... so it might help. And actually it should work on 64 bit Systems. XD