# Using Cisco VPN in Windows 7 XP Mode?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp-mode, cisco-vpn-client

I previously asked a question about whether it was possible to use Cisco VPN client on Windows 7 64-bit (see below).

Now that I have it set up, it doesn't work when I try to connect off the local network.  I realize that there must be some networking/routing that I need to do since it's running on a virtual machine.  How does one go about using the Cisco VPN client from XP mode in Windows 7?

Related: [Cisco VPN Client on Windows 7 64-bit?](https://superuser.com/questions/72425/cisco-vpn-client-on-windows-7-64-bit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do this.  You just need to change the network adapter for the virtual machine (simple instructions [on this blog post](http://chrisjakeway.wordpress.com/2009/10/23/windows-7-xp-mode-network-settings/)):

> In Windows 7:
>
> Start -> All Programs -> Windows
>   Virtual PC -> Virtual Machines Right
>   click on your virtual machine
>   configuration file.  e.g. Virtual
>   Windows XP.vmcx Select Settings from
>   the right-click menu In the Virtual PC
>   Settings dialog, select Networking on
>   the left. Change the Adapter drop down
>   box on the right from Shared Network
>   (NAT) to the name of your Ethernet
>   card. Press OK Start/Restart the XP VM
>   image.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [Shrew Soft VPN](http://www.shrew.net/) and VPNC Front End as alternatives to Cisco's own client on Windows 7 x64. Both worked but I had to manually tweak the routing tables to when connecting from my home LAN.

Also, VPNC FE didn't work out of the box. It did when I installed OpenVPN TAP driver before it (downloaded OpenVPN, unchecked everything but the driver in  its installation program).